# AttributeError : 'XMLParser' object has no attribute 'charset'

Tags: python, xml-parsing, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have the following view in my project:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 100
    filter_class = MyFilter
    renderer_classes = (XMLParser, )
```

When I make the get request however I get this error:

```
AttributeError :'XMLParser' object has no attribute 'charset'
```

What could be the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `XMLParser` to the `renderer_classes` tuple. Django Rest Framework does not know what to do with that. Instead, you should be adding an XML **Renderer** to the `renderer_classes` rather than an XML **Parser**

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 100
    filter_class = MyFilter
    renderer_classes = (XMLRenderer, )
```

If your intention is to add an XML **Parser** you need to set the `parser_classes` tuple

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 100
    filter_class = MyFilter
    parser_classes = (XMLParser, )
```